# Unable to Extract trust manager on IBM JRE8 with OKHTTP3

Tags: okhttp, trustmanager, x509trustmanager, ibm-jre

Can Any one help on this please.

I am also using **OKHTTP3 version 4.8.1** to write **HTTP2 client** . Its Working on Oracle JDK 8 but not working on IBM JRE 8.

Error message:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on okhttp3.internal.Platform@e85a0ce8, sslSocketFactory is class com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.

Thank you

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts of your code please?

Comment: i was  using this Deprecated method of OKhttp3 jar.
  sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory).After replacing it  with   sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory,trustManager). issue resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are relying on a long deprecated method

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/cd722373281202492043f4294fccfe6f691ddc01/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.kt#L741

It's deprecated because it had to assume a lot about the JVM, that breaks on each JVM update or across vendors.  You should instead call the method with X509TrustManager as a parameter

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/cd722373281202492043f4294fccfe6f691ddc01/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.kt#L767

```
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
        + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
}
X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
    .build();
```

Comment: This code was  fix for  error "Unable to extract the trust manager".Thank you for help

Comment: On Next step , ALPN config is not working for Webshere 9 and Java 8.                                                           
 Sending HTTP2 request to Apple push server using OKhttp3 client.

Server: Webshere 9 Java : 8 OKhttp3 :4.8.1 Also added ALPN jar in boot classpath. ALPN jar version mapped accurately with JDK version in bootclasspath.

Getting this error message in IBM Webshere 9 log file. ALPN callback dropped: HTTP/2 is disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I suggest asking as a separate question so more people see it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826143/alpn-callback-dropped-http-2-is-disabled-is-alpn-boot-on-the-boot-class-path    thanks