# ALPN callback dropped: HTTP/2 is disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path" on IBM Webshere 9 JAVA 8

Tags: apple-push-notifications, okhttp, http2, alpn, websphere-9

Need help  on this.

Sending HTTP2 request to Apple push server using OKhttp3 client.

Server:  Webshere 9
Java  :   8
OKhttp3 :4.8.1
Also added ALPN jar in boot classpath.
ALPN jar version   mapped accurately  with JDK version in bootclasspath.

Getting this error message in IBM Webshere 9 log file.
**ALPN callback dropped: HTTP/2 is disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?**

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

If you can upgrade past Java 8u252 then you won't need alpn-boot on the bootclasspath

https://webtide.com/jetty-alpn-java-8u252/

I suggest looking at whether this is possible first.